# A Navigation Drawer with a mobile header in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ){
            $('.header').addClass('header2');
        } else {
            $('.header').removeClass('header2');
        }
    });

});
```

I am really new to the world of web development and I am trying to make a navigation drawer with a moving header. When you scroll down, the button that activates the navigation bar would remain at the top of the header and you can tap it. In my code this button seems fine, but it can't activate the navigation bar. For some unknown reason, when including the button in the header, it stops activating the navigation bar. Any kind of help you can give me is welcome.

This is my code:

```css
* {margin:0; padding:0;}

body{background:#fffffA;}

header {
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#252932;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.wrapper {
    width:90%;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

header .logo {
    color:#f2f2f2;
    font-size:50px;
    font-family:"Nexa";
    line-height:200px;
    float:left;
}

header nav {
    float:right;
    line-height:200px;
}

header nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:normal;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:"Nexa";
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

header nav a:hover {
    background:#F56F3A;
    border-radius:50px;
}

.header2 {
    position: fixed;
    height:100px;

}

.header2 .logo {
    line-height:100px;
    font-size:30px;
}

.header2 nav {
    line-height:100px;
}

.contenido p {
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

.contenido h3 {
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    background:#F56F3A;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1025px) {
    header .logo,
    header nav {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:100px;
    }

    .header2 {
        height:auto;
    }

    .header2 .logo{
        line-height:50px;
    }

    .header2 nav {
        line-height:50px;
    }
}


body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    background-color:#fafafa;
  }
  
  .OpenMenuButton { cursor: pointer; }
  
  .DrawerMenu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'MENU OVERLAY';
    -ms-grid-columns: 15fr 5fr;
    grid-template-columns: 15fr 5fr
  }
   @media (min-width: 30em) {
  
  .DrawerMenu {
    -ms-grid-columns: 5fr 10fr;
    grid-template-columns: 5fr 10fr;
  }
  }
  
  #DrawerMenuTrigger:checked ~ .DrawerMenu {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  
  .MenuContainer {
    grid-area: 'MENU';
    background-color: rgb(18, 8, 109);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 24px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  
  .Menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap
  }
  
  .Menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 16px 0;
  }
  
  .Menu a + a { border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); }
  
  .MenuOverlay { grid-area: 'OVERLAY'; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"> <!-- ACA SE IMPORTA EL CSS DE BOOSTRAP PARA HACERLO MÁS LINDO EN EL DEFAULT-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="header.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 
<header class="header">

  
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="logo">Name</div>
    
    <nav>
      
      <a href="#" >
        <label for="DrawerMenuTrigger" class="OpenMenuButton" >
          <image src = "images.ico"></image>
        </label> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="DrawerMenuTrigger"  onclick= f() hidden>
      
    </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="contenido wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</section>


<aside class="DrawerMenu" > 
  <div class="MenuContainer" > 
    <nav class="Menu" > 
      <a><image src = "images.png"></image></a>
      <a>User</a>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a> 
      <a href="#">Item 2</a> 
      <a href="#">Item 3</a> 
      <a href="#">Item 4</a> 
    </nav>
  </div>
  <label for="DrawerMenuTrigger" class="MenuOverlay"></label> 
</aside>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt0Tm.png)

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include the `header.js` file.

Comment: Ohh thanks, try now